# Android Studio 2.1.2 rendering issue

Tags: java, android

I've installed android studio 2.1.2 . I've developed a few basic apps using it but and ran them in my android device. However, in the activity_main.xml design tab, the preview never appeared. I could see my interface in my device when I ran it, but it doesn't show any preview in the design tab. I've attached a photo of the screen here.

[image: This is the error notice.]

I would be glad to have a preview prior to actually running my app on the device. I've already installed JDK 8 and set the path appropriately, but still no luck.

Comment: installing support sdk may be helpful

Comment: if you think it is problem with studio you can try updating studio to 2.2 beta

Comment: IIRC IDEA/Android Studio comes with a bundled JRE. Try renaming/deleting the `jre` directory inside of Android Studio, and it should run using the default system JRE.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the Android version to use when rendering layouts in the IDE to **23**.

In your designer view, click the Android Icon showing API version **24** & change it to **23**.

Answer (score 0):

simply studio is trying to tell you to `update your jdk version` because sooner or later you will have to do it and there are too many reasons to do this , like `improve performance , rectified issues of older versions, new features etc`.

If you `don't want to update java` than you can use the `option` `suggested by @sJy` but the drawback is , you won't be able to use the preview functions of `android N` like 'dual activity ' etc, which will be required one day, while developing an `app with android N features`

If you already have `java 8` installed then you can update `JAVA_HOME` `environment variable` path to your `java 8` `Jdk` folder.

you may need to use `openjdk` that is embedded into new anroid studio for better performance .

Comment: Thanks for the answer Pavneet. But I've already installed JDK 8 and set the path variables and still no go.

Comment: you can check that your studio is also using JDK 8 , Project Structure => sdk location=> jdk path(make sure using jdk 8) if still no go try clear cache and restart or if still no  go then last option is updating studio

Comment: I tried that too. and I've installed the beta version of Android 2.2 but it won't give me luck :(

Comment: The image you showed already had the 24 api selected nothing else was  there to think.